# Prevent duplication of node text in treeview (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, treeview, duplicates

Process: A node is added in a treeview control with node text = textbox1.text

I want to prevent addition of duplicate node i.e. say, if a node with text "ABC" is added then next time, a node with text "ABC" should not be added to treeview control.

I tried following methods but could not achieve desired result.
Method A)

```
Dim list As New ArrayList
list.Add(TextBox1.Text) 
if list.Contains(Textbox1.Text) then
       MsgBox("Use different name")
else 
       .....code to add node with text
end if
```

Method B)

```
if Treeview1.Nodes.Count > 0 then 
   For i = 0 to Treeview1.Nodes.Count
      if Treeview1.Nodes(i).Text=Textbox1.Text then
         MsgBox("Use different name")
      end if
   next
else 
   ........code to add node with text
end if
```

I could not understand the solutions suggested for C# on this forum.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method A should work OK. You might have another error in your code (in the else section?). `list` should be declared static if it is in a function that's being called repeatedly, else it will be reset to new (cleared) each time.

Method B has a couple of errors: (1) the for statement should be `For i = 0 to Treeview1.Nodes.Count - 1` (maybe use "for each"), and the `else` with the code to add the node should be after the `msgbox` statement. Also, method B only search for the root node(s) of the treeview. You would need to traverse the tree to check all the nodes.

Comment: Method B + your suggested modifications = solution. I tried Method A again but it adds the duplicate node. I am not sure what is wrong there. Thank you so much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

```
If ListView1.Items.Count > 0 Then
                For I = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
                    For Each LVL As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
                        If ListView1.Items.Item(I).Index = LVL.Index Then
                            Continue For
                        Else
                            If ListView1.Items.Item(I).Text = LVL.Text Then 
                                LVL.Remove()
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
           End If
```